# RandomizedSearchCV sampling without replacement

Tags: scikit-learn

I am a little confused with the statement

> If all parameters are presented as a list, sampling without replacement is performed. If at least one parameter is given as a distribution, sampling with replacement is used. It is highly recommended to use continuous distributions for continuous parameters.

in sklearn RandomizedSearchCV [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html). What does it mean by sampling without replacement?

Suppose I have a model where my parameters are defined as

```
params = {C:[1, 10, 100, 1000],
gamma: [1,2,3,4,5],
col_sample: [0.6,0.8,.09]}
```

How will the sampling without replacement happen above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sampling without replacement means, that **no** parameter combination will be used **more than once**.

For the  `RandomizedSearchCV`, that means that each possible parameter combination with `C`, `gamma`, and `col_sample` will be tested **once at most**.